# nginx: regex not working on url rewrite

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url

I have `http://sample.cervo02.com`. i'm trying to get `https://cervo02.com/sample`.

**I tried  couple of redirect none of them are working.**  `rewrite ^([^.]*)$ https://cervo02.com/$1 last;` return `https://cervo02.com//`

the other one is `rewrite ^([^.]*).cervo02.com$ https://cervo02.com/$1 last;` return a 404 and the url is not rewritten.

the complete server host definition

```
upstream backend {
    server 192.167.1.79:8080;
}

proxy_cache_path  /tmp/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my-test-cache:8m max_size=5000m inactive=300m;



server {
     listen   80;

    server_name sample.CERVO02.com;


    rewrite ^([^.]*)$ https://cervo02.com/$1 last;

}

server {

    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    server_name  CERVO02.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;



    location / {

       proxy_pass http://backend;# backend c'est pas une variable 

        proxy_cache my-test-cache;
        proxy_cache_valid  200 302  60m;
        proxy_cache_valid  404      1m;
        proxy_cache_use_stale   error timeout invalid_header updating;
        proxy_redirect default;
    }
 }
```

any help is welcome thanks again.

Comment: Please add the complete virtual host definition properly formatted to the question.

Comment: i just did it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rewrite` directive regex will match the normalized request **URI** while the `server_name` directive will match the domain name. The `last` flag will force an internal redirect and that's not what you want.

So you are doing it the wrong way.

Use this instead :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name "~^(?<subdomain>[^.]*)\.?cervo02.com$";
    return 301 https://cervo02.com/$subdomain;
}
```